# convert millisecond to DateTime in HTML page YII

Tags: yii

how to convert millisecond to datetime in yii?

*ps : in this code my Date_In in millisecond

here is my code:

`<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('Date_In')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->Date_In); ?>
    <br />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formatDateTime](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#formatDateTime-detail) function of yii;

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($data->Date_In, 'long', false); ?>
```

Or simply [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of PHP

```
<?php echo date('d.m.Y', $data->Date_In); ?>
```